# How to cut highlight in iOS Charts only up to the data point?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

How can I customize the highlighter in Line Charts? I want to cut the highlight to be drawn only up to the data point. I also want to customize the label on the x-axis where it's highlighted. Below is a reference picture on what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

This is what I've done so far. [What I've achieved so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W629u.png)

Below is the code for my Line Chart View Setup

```
let lineChartView: LineChartView = {
    let chart = LineChartView(frame: .zero)
    chart.chartDescription = nil
    chart.dragEnabled = true
    chart.scaleYEnabled = false
    chart.scaleXEnabled = true
    chart.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    chart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = true
    chart.gridBackgroundColor = .clear
    chart.legend.enabled = false
    chart.zoom(scaleX: 2, scaleY: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
    chart.setViewPortOffsets(left: 30, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30)

    chart.rightAxis.enabled = false

    let yAxis = chart.leftAxis
    yAxis.enabled = true
    yAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
    yAxis.gridColor = UIColor(rgba: "#414042")
    yAxis.gridLineWidth = 1
    yAxis.axisMaximum = 6000

    chart.xAxis.enabled = true
    chart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    chart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    chart.xAxis.axisLineColor = .darkGray
    chart.xAxis.axisLineWidth = 1
    chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
    chart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    chart.xAxis.labelTextColor = .darkGray
    chart.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.sourceSansProLight(withSize: 15.5)
    chart.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    chart.xAxis.granularity = 1

    chart.highlightPerTapEnabled = false

    chart.backgroundColor = .clear

    return chart
}()
```

And this is the code for adding random data points in the chart and the highlight.

```
var values: [ChartDataEntry] = []
var highlight: Highlight? = nil

for index in 0..<12 {
    let randomValue = Double(arc4random_uniform(5000))
    values.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: randomValue))

    if index == 4 {
        highlight = Highlight(x: Double(index), y: randomValue, dataSetIndex: 0)
    }
}

let dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: values, label: "")
dataSet.highlightEnabled = true
dataSet.drawHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = false
dataSet.highlightColor = UIColor(rgba: "#1899FF")
dataSet.highlightLineWidth = 1
dataSet.mode = .horizontalBezier
dataSet.circleColors = Array(repeating: UIColor(rgba: "#1899FF"), count: 12)
dataSet.fillColor = UIColor(rgba: "#1899FF")
dataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = false
dataSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
dataSet.lineWidth = 0.0
dataSet.drawValuesEnabled = true
dataSet.axisDependency = .left
dataSet.valueFormatter = self

let data = LineChartData(dataSet: dataSet)
data.setDrawValues(true)
data.setValueFont(UIFont.sourceSansProLight(withSize: 15.5))
data.setValueTextColor(UIColor(rgba: "#1899FF"))

lineChartView.data = data
lineChartView.highlightValue(highlight)
```

Comment: The question is to broad. Why have you not posted the code you already have? What have you tried?

Comment: oh, I thought I got my question right. I'll add a reference screenshot on what I've already done and some code. But basically, I just need to make the x-axis label Bold and with a different color if it's part of the highlighted point and I have to cut the highlight line only up to the data point.

Comment: @Bjørn updated my question

Comment: in the _drawHighlightLines_ function in whichever chart you're using LineScatterCandleRadarRenderer.swift for me), change the line

`context.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: viewPortHandler.contentTop))`

to

`context.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: viewPortHandler.contentTop + point.y - offsetOfMarkerToHighlightLine))`

Comment: @taki, did you get the solution? plz share if possible

Answer (score 0):

For Highlight Area of data point you can use below property and achieve this

All property can use through dataSet so for that you can create `LineChartDataSet` like below and use different property as per your requirement.

```
//DataSet
LineChartDataSet *set = [[LineChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:values label:@"closed"];
set.lineWidth = 2;
```

**Set ChartFill property with your fill color :**

```
 set.fill = [ChartFill fillWithColor:<Your Legend Color>];
 [set setColor:<Your Legend Color>];
 [set setCircleColor:<Your Legend Color>];
 [set setCircleHoleColor:<Your Legend Color>];
```

**You need to enable drawfill :**

```
set.drawFilledEnabled = YES;
```

**You can Enable circle with this property :**

```
[set setDrawCirclesEnabled:YES];
```

**You can enable highlight Indicator which dat point is selected will highlight with Vertical Line :**

```
[set setDrawHighlightIndicators:YES];
```

**You can set Circle radius as per your requirement :**

```
[set setCircleRadius:5.0f];
[set setCircleHoleRadius:4.0f];
```

**You can specify line with of highlighted data point also :**

```
[set setHighlightLineWidth:1.0];
[set setHighlightColor:kAppLegend3GraphColorForCAP];
```

**Edit:**

for changing font color & type you need to change xAxis color and font as mention below

```
lineChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
lineChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = .orange
```

*For Line limit to data point value I think we can not limit this in current version.*

Hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Sorry, updated my question. I just needed to customize the hightlight line and change the font style of the x-axis label if it's x value is highlighted

Comment: ok so for xAxis color you can make it bold and and custom font and color but for limit datapoint line I think its not possible.

Comment: how about the highlight line?

Comment: I think thats not possible in current library but still you can search or try your self hope you will get nay success on this point.